# Разделение строки на несколько ключей с одним значением. HashMap

Tags: java

Нужна помощь. Программа по введённому коду определяет страну.
Я беру таблицу из википедии

```
public class TableLoad {
private Map<String, String> codes = new HashMap<>();
private String link = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes";
private Integer hashMapSize = 0;
private Document document = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
public TableLoad() throws IOException {
    Element table = document.select("table.wikitable").get(1);
    Elements body = table.select("tbody");
    Elements rows = body.select("tr");

    for (Element row : rows) {
        Elements columns = row.select("td");
        if (columns.size() > 2) {
            String name = columns.get(0).text();
            String code = columns.get(1).text().replace(" ", "");
            codes.put(code, name);
        }
    }
    codes.forEach((n, c) -> System.out.println(n + " -> " + c));
    hashMapSize = codes.size();
}
```

Получаю список такого образца

[image: Получаю список такого образца]

Как видно на картинке, некоторые ключи содержат два или более кодов.
Как их разделить и присвоить то же значение в том же мапе?
например

+1284 -> British Virgin Islands

+8812 -> Ellipso
+8813 -> Ellipso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```
String name = columns.get(0).text();
String code = columns.get(1).text().replace(" ", "");

int plusCount = code.chars().filter(x -> x == '+').count();
if (plusCount > 1) {
     for (String codeEntry : code.split(",")) { codes.put(codeEntry, name); }
} else {
    codes.put(code, name);
}
```

Comment: А зачем `plusCount`? `split(",")` и хватит

Comment: Просто так) Не буду возражать против правки ответа - самому лень)

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Пока ждал ответа, взял другую таблицу.

Answer (score 1):

Просто разбивайте строку кода по запятой и добавляйте разные ключи в Map

```java
String name = columns.get(0).text();
String code = columns.get(1).text().replace(" ", "");
for (String codeEntry : code.split(",")) {
  codes.put(codeEntry, name);
}
```